# Find dV/dA in terms of r.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

The volume of a sphere, $V$ cm³, of radius $r$ is given by the formula $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$. The surface area of a sphere $A$ cm² of radius $r$ cm is given by the formula $A=4\pi r^2$. Find $dV/dA$ in terms of $r$.

Here's my workings to the question:

$$V= \frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^{3}}{4\pi r^2}A = \frac{1}{3}rA$$

So, $$\frac{dV}{dA} = \frac{1}{3}r =\frac{r}{3}.$$

I am not sure about this answer, so it would help to know if anyone got the same answer. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how you leapt from $V = \frac{rA}{3}$ to $\frac{dV}{dA} = \frac{r}{3}.$

Comment: I think I made a mistake assuming that r was a constant

Comment: $A$ is a function of $r$, so if you differentiated both sides you would get $\frac{dV}{dr} = \frac{A+r\frac{dA}{dr}}{3}$.

Comment: You're forgetting that $r$ can be expressed as a function of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is fine, but remember that in order to take the derivative $\frac{dV}{dA}$ directly you need to completely eliminate $r$ from your equation first.  So, since you have $A = 4\pi r^{2}$, you can solve for $r$ to get $r = \frac{A^{1/2}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$.  Then, substituting this into $V = \frac{1}{3}rA$ you get $$V = \frac{1}{3}\frac{A^{3/2}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}.$$  Now you can take the derivative directly, to get $$\frac{dV}{dA} = \frac{A^{1/2}}{4\sqrt{\pi}}.$$  Since the question wanted your answer in terms of $r$, we substitute back: $$\frac{dV}{dA} = \frac{A^{1/2}}{4\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{A^{1/2}}{2\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac{1}{2}r = \frac{r}{2}.$$

That said, as was pointed out in another post, you could also compute this by finding $\frac{dV}{dr}$ and $\frac{dA}{dr}$ separately, and then using the chain rule: $$\frac{dV}{dA} = \frac{dV}{dr}\cdot \frac{dr}{dA}.$$  However, in either case you  should arrive at the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given $V= \frac{4\pi}3 r^3$ and $A=4\pi r^2$, we have

$$V= \frac{4\pi}3\left(\frac{A}{4\pi}\right)^{3/2}= \frac{A^{3/2}}{3\sqrt{4\pi}}
$$

Then,

$$\frac{dV}{dA}= \frac12\frac{\sqrt A}{\sqrt{4\pi}}= \frac r2
$$

Answer (score 1):

The physicist way.
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{dV}{dA}&=\lim_{\Delta r\to0}\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta A}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta r\to0}\left(\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta r}\right)/\left(\frac{\Delta A}{\Delta r}\right)\\
&=\lim_{\Delta r\to0}\left(\frac43\pi\frac{(r+\Delta r)^3-r^3}{\Delta r}\right)/\left(4\pi\frac{(r+\Delta r)^2-r^2}{\Delta r}\right)\\
&=\frac{r^2}{2r}\\
&=\frac r2
\end{align*}$$